# Golang: unsafe dynamic byte array

Tags: arrays, pointers, dll, go

I am trying to interface with a Windows dll using Go. The dll function I want to use accepts a pointer to a byte array. Therefore I need to give it that byte array.

I am using the [syscall](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) libary to call the dll, as demonstrated [here](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/WindowsDLLs). My basic requirements are:

- I am given the required size for the byte array
- I create the byte array
- I must get a pointer to the byte array
- I then pass the pointer to the Windows dll

I can't figure out how to create a byte array in go, and get a pointer to it. This is obviously an unsafe operation, and the [unsafe](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) library can be helpful, but I need to create a dynamic-length byte array in the first place. Creating a slice with "make" doesn't help me, unless I can get a pointer to the slice's backing array.

Has anyone else encountered this or have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think syscall.ComputerName implementation https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go#395 would be a good example. It uses uint16s, not bytes, but otherwise ...

In your case it would be `ptr := &myslice[0]`.

Alex

Answer (score 3):

Well I found one gross solution. Apparently the [structure of a slice](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals#TOC_4.) contains a pointer to the backing byte array, the length of the backing byte array, and then the capacity of the backing byte array.

I am only interested in a pointer to the byte array, so I only need the first member of the slice's internal data.

Go's `unsafe.Pointer` will not cast a slice to an unsafe pointer, but it will cast a pointer to a slice as an unsafe pointer. Since I can cast an unsafe pointer to any old type of pointer I want, I can cast it to a pointer-to-a-pointer, which recovers the first member of the slice's internal data.

Here's a working example. I wanted a `uintptr` but you could cast it to any pointer type.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    // Arbitrary size
    n := 4

    // Create a slice of the correct size
    m := make([]int, n)

    // Use convoluted indirection to cast the first few bytes of the slice
    // to an unsafe uintptr
    mPtr := *(*uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&m))

    // Check it worked
    m[0] = 987
    // (we have to recast the uintptr to a *int to examine it)
    fmt.Println(m[0], *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(mPtr)))
}
```

If you wanted a `*int` instead, you could do `mPtr := *(**int)(unsafe.Pointer(&m))`

This works as long as a slice maintains this internal data structure. I am definitely open to a more robust solution that doesn't depend on the structure of Go's internals.

Comment: Pointer to first element of backing array of m := make([]int, 10) slice is &m[0].

Comment: My bad. I had tried what I thought was &m[0] before, and was getting a pointer to a copy of what was at m[0]. Obviously I did something wrong, because trying it now, it works fine.